# How do Saving Throw bonuses interact with multiple effect conditions?

Tags: dnd-4e

A warforged character has a +2 racial bonus to saving throws against ongoing damage.

Does the bonus apply if he's afflicted with 5 ongoing + dazed and a save ends both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The bonus would apply to the save.

The status effect includes ongoing damage. Therefore, it meets the condition of "saving throw against ongoing damage." There is no other qualifier in the power so there is nothing to prevent it from applying.

Were the conditions separate, he would only get the bonus against the damage. But, because they are combined he gets it against the combined effect.

Comment: I take it that this also applies to stuff that lets you roll a saving throw against a particular effect, e.g. Superior Will when you're Dazed&Weakened (save ends both).

Comment: @Ravn yes it does.